# How to add two offset in python?

Tags: python, timezone, python-2.7

I am getting a offset form the pytz library from the following line:

```
 offset = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(timezone)).strftime('%z')
```

First i pass the `US/Eastern` in `timezone` variable
and then i pass the `Asia/Kolkata` in `timezone` variable which prints the following value

```
 local_utc = -0400
 user_utc = +0530
```

After getting these values i converted it from string to int by following code:

```
local_utc = int(local_utc)
user_urc = int(user_utc)
```

Apart from this i have a timetuple also:

```
 hour, minute,days = (timezone_tuple.tm_hour, timezone_tuple.tm_min,
                        timezone_tuple.tm_mday)
```

I want to add the difference of `local_utc and user_utc` to above tuple such as -0400: `04` such as hour and `00` as minutes.
For example: difference will be : `0930`. And `09` will be add to `timezone_tuple.tm_hour` and `30` will be add to `timezone_tuple.tm_min`

I didn't found any situation. how can it be possible? 
Is there any way to do with `spilit` method

Comment: Isnt the difference in time zones 9 hours and 30 minutes, not 1.5 hours?

Comment: How are you getting the offsets from pytz? Is `local_utc` a string? If you tell Python `local_utc = -0400`, then `local_utc` is set to the integer -256, since Python interprets numbers that begin with a zero as an octal.

Comment: let me put the code form where i am getting the offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post showed how to find `local_utc` and `user_utc` as integers. You could just take the difference `local_utc-user_utc` to determine the relative offset.

However, `datetime`, `time` and `pytz` should give you all the tools you need to manipulate times without having to parse offsets and do such calculations "manually".

For example,

```
import pytz
import datetime as dt
import time

eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
kolkata = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

naive_timetuple = time.localtime(0)
print(naive_timetuple)
# time.struct_time(tm_year=1969, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=19, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=365, tm_isdst=0)
```

Above, I defined a naive timetuple. Below, I "localize" it to US/Eastern time -- that is, make it a timezone-aware datetime:

```
naive_datetime = dt.datetime(*naive_timetuple[:6])
print(naive_datetime)
# 1969-12-31 19:00:00

localized_datetime = eastern.localize(naive_datetime)
print(localized_datetime)
# 1969-12-31 19:00:00-05:00
```

Now to convert a timezone-aware datetime to any other timezone, use the `astimezone` method:

```
kolkata_datetime = localized_datetime.astimezone(kolkata)
print(kolkata_datetime)
# 1970-01-01 05:30:00+05:30
```

And if you need to convert a datetime back to a timetuple, use the timetuple method:

```
kolkata_timetuple = kolkata_datetime.timetuple()
print(kolkata_timetuple)
# time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=5, tm_min=30, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the giving very specific explanation :)